# Powershell Python

Tags: python, powershell

What happens when you type python in windows powershell? It shows me the python version but what can you do inside it since you can't really use it to display code you've written on an editor, right?

Comment: It's not for *displaying* code, it's for *executing* code. And this question has nothing to do with Powershell.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is *NOT* a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts the Python [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) or Python in interactive Mode.